# How can I add a tooltip when mouse is over an item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want wen I click on first paragraph, the element with id « envoie » shows up as a tooltip and disappear when mouse leave.

What I have is the tooltip is display une the first element. I mean when I click on the last « first element », the tooltip is still under the first element.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.envoie-fr, .ship-fr {
margin-top: -25px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2000;
  visibility: visible;
  .transition(all 0.1s linear);

}

</style>

<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {

    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#envoie");
console.log(x.length);

  });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div>
  <p class="#envoie">First Paragraph</p>
  <div id="envoie" class="envoie-fr">Envoie</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p class="#ship">Second Paragraph</p>
    <div id="ship" class="ship-fr">Ship</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <div>
  <p class="#envoie">First Paragraph</p>
  <div id="envoie" class="envoie-fr">Envoie</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p class="#ship">Second Paragraph</p>
    <div id="ship" class="ship-fr">Ship</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <p class="#example" style="margin-top:50px">Bottom</p> 
</div>



</body>
</html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

myDiv.onmouseenter = function() { 
 // do your stuff to show element like display:block;
  alert('entered');
}

myDiv.onmouseout = function() {
// do your stuff to hide element like display:none; 
  alert('left');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the title tag as a tooltip to the HTML element.

Comment: Can you add quick explaination in your answer such as code ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any script to make that happened. Also, from your issue title I can tell that you want the tooltip be displayed on hover (not on click) and disappeared when the mouse is away (this is how actually tooltips work). So, here is the code for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        /*optional: these are to make the content centered*/
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      div {
        /*optional*/
        border: solid 1px #f9cd23;
        padding: 30px;
      }
      p {
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        margin: 40px 0;
      }

      /*for the tooltip box*/
      p:hover:after {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        background: #f9cd23;
        border-radius: 8px;
        color: black;
        content: attr(title);
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 200px;
      }

      /*for the tooltip triangle*/
      p:hover:before {
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        top: -20px;
        position: absolute;
        border: solid;
        border-color: #f9cd23 transparent;
        border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
        content: '';
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <p title="This is the first paragraph tooltip...">First Paragraph</p>
      <p title="This is the second paragraph tooltip...">Second Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have another question... What if I replace the p marker with an img marker... I tried that but the css does not take effects...

Comment: to solve that, just include your <img> tag inside the <p> tags I provided for you in my solution. Then, alter the "top" property value for "p:hover::after" and "p:hover::before" based on your image size. (check my codepen: https://codepen.io/zaaraa-z/pen/zYzQWjZ)

Comment: Yeah Thanks ... I notice that when I maintain the cursor on the image, the tooltip we design shows up but the default one too shows up. I mean when maintaining the cursor on the img, I will get 2 tooltip

Comment: I got it. I have to change the title attribute by an alt attribute for examle

Comment: Correct. Title attribute is there to show you the default tooltip, which we want to make it more formatted and styled. So, you just change it to another semantic attribute and use that in css too.

Comment: @Racsom Is the issue solved? if positive, please accept my answer and close it. Thanks